# Unable to load an OSM .bz2 file into a PostGIS database using osm2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, qgis-2, osm2pgsql

Following is the query :
C:>osm2pgsql -c --slim -d osm_1 -U postgres -H localhost -S C:\default.style C:\mumbai_india.osm.pbf

Following is the error on which i am stuck:

```
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
PREPARE get_way (int4) AS SELECT AsText(way) FROM planet_osm_point WHERE osm_id
= $1;
 failed: ERROR:  function astext(geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: PREPARE get_way (int4) AS SELECT AsText(way) FROM planet_osm...
                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Error occurred, cleaning up
```

Following is the version of osm2pgsql:

```
C:\>osm2pgsql
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.69-21289M
```

I am using Windows 7 64bit PC with PostgreSql database installed with pgAdmin4..
I did pass various  osm.pbf files in the above query but still getting the same issue.
I went through various post and solutions and also created Extension postgis and Extension hstore in the database named osm_1 in pgAdmin4 postgresql but still the same issue..

I re-installed osm2pgsql with the latest version found on Google but still got the same error..

Comment: Osm2pgsql seems to use deprecated function. It is called ST_AsText nowadays. 900913 may lead to problems as well because it is officially 3857. Perhaps your version is oldish.

Comment: Did you add the extension Postgis to the db osm_1?

Answer (score 2):

Your version of osm2pgsql is outdated, and does not respect changes that were made for Postgis 2.0

You can get the latest windows builds here: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/472

Alternatively (or if you run into similar problems with Mapnik), you can run the legacy.sql which brings back the old functions to Postgis 2.0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945821/postgresql-install-of-legacy-sql-osm-data-and-posgis-2-0